# Proof: $\tan(x)$ is surjective from $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ onto $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing

To prove $\tan(x)$ defined on $\big{(} -\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}{2}\big)$ is injective I take the derivative of $\tan(x)$ to get $\sec(x)^2$.
This shows that $\tan(x)$ is monotonic (strictly) increasing which implies it is injective from the domain onto the real line.

However how do I show it is surjective ? In other words, how do I show that every single real number corresponds to some number in the domain of $\tan(x)$ ?

Comment: Use the triangle definition of tangent. Show that given any real number you can construct a triangle which will give the desired value of tangent.

Comment: It's continuous on $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ (open interval) and approaches $\pm\infty$ at the endpoints.

Comment: As pointed out by Gerry, you may show that it's continuous on $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, calculate it's limits on the endpoints and use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: You should clearly state the domain since if you just say $\tan$ then it usually it is assumed that the domain is all of $\mathbb{R}$ in which case it is not injective.

Comment: Are there no easy way ? In our course we haven't been introduced to  analsysis of continuity event though I know what it is.

Comment: If you accept the correspondence between $\mathbb{R}$ and a line in the plane in a manner described by coordinated geometry, then for any positive number $x$, you can always construct a right angled triangle with side $1$ and side $x$ and you will get an angle $\theta$ with $\tan\theta = x$. If you further accept $\tan\theta$ is an odd function in $\theta$, then you are done.

Comment: If you know that $\sin(x) : [0, \pi/2 ]$ to $[0,1]$ is onto, then all you need to do is prove that the function $f(s)=\frac{s}{\sqrt{1-s^2}} : [0,1) \to [0, \infty)$ is onto, and that is easy....

Answer (score 4):

I can see that a rigorous analytical proof for the surjectivity of $f\colon(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\to\mathbb{R}$, where $f(x)=\tan(x)$, is a way far off. However, I wanted to give a picture of what @achillehui mentioned in a comment, as it is rather beautiful in my opinion:

$\color{white}{Put it in the center!!!!!!!}$[image]

Given the picture above, we note that
$$
\tan(\theta)=\frac{x}{1}=x\qquad\text{and}\qquad\tan(-\theta)=-\frac{x}{1}=-x.
$$
Hence, we can "clearly" see that
$$
\lim_{\theta\to\pi/2^-}\tan(\theta)=\infty\qquad\text{and}\qquad\lim_{-\theta\to-\pi/2^+}\tan(-\theta)=-\infty.\qquad\approx\blacksquare
$$

Comment: I think you're being too harsh about this argument being unrigorous. It establishes a bijection between angles in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and signed lengths in $(-\infty,\infty)$. I fail to see where the argument would be faulty.

Answer (score 1):

The above use of the intermediate value theorem uses $\overline{\mathbb R}$ to accomplish its task, but also seems to beg the question by asserting the one-sided limits of tangent at $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.  Here is a proof that does not use either geometry or $\overline{\mathbb R}$ The proof will however use various derivative rules including L'Hospital and Intermediate Value Theorem (all of which can clearly be derived in a noncircular manner)

$\forall x\in\mathbb R$, it is clear there $\exists k\in\mathbb N$ at which $2^k \ge x$ (proof found elsewhere).  We can use this fact to show tangent is surjective on $\mathbb R$ on the $\mathcal D_{\tan}(-\frac{pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ without resorting to geometry.

The derivative of $f(x) = \frac{tan(\frac{\pi/2+x}{2})}{tan(x)}$ is, after plenty of simplification, $\frac{1}{cos(\frac{\pi/2+x}{2})sin(x)} (\frac{cos(x)}{2cos(\frac{\pi/2+x}{2})} - \frac{sin(\frac{\pi/2+x}{2})}{sin(x)})$.  This function can be seen to be negative on the domain $(\pi/4,\pi/2)$.

The limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $\pi/2$ is 2, and is easily findable using the chain rule as well as L'Hopital rule.  Then it is clear since the derivative is negative and the minimum is 2, that all values of $x$ on the open interval $(\pi/4,\pi/2)$ have $f(x) \ge 2$.

This is when the pieces start to fall into place.  Let's form the sequence $a_i$ defined by $a_1 = \pi/4$, $a_j = (\pi/2 + a_{j-1})/2$ for all other $j$.  We've already shown that for all $j > 1$, $\frac{\tan(a_j)}{\tan(a_{j-1})} \ge 2$.  It is therefore clear that for all real $r>=1$, there is some $i_1$ where $tan(a_{i_1}) \ge 2^{{i_1}-1} \ge r$ (from the above mentioned theorem).

Since $\tan(-x) = -\tan(x)$, the same principle can be applied to any negative real $r <= -1$ to find an $i_2$ where $tan(-a_{i_2}) \le -2^{{i_2}-1} \le r$. These two values are appropriate for use in the intermediate value theorem to show there must exist some value $k$ in $(a_{i_2},a_{i_1})$ where $\tan(k) = r$.

Comment: Use backslashes before functions so they are rendered with correct spacing and are explicitly not variables, e.g., `$\tan x$` for $\tan x$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\tan x = \sin x / \cos x$. Since $\sin$ and $\cos$ are continuous and $\sin (\pm \pi/2) = \pm 1$ and $\cos(\pm \pi/2) = 0$, we see that $\lim_{x \to \pm\pi/2} \tan x = \pm \infty$. Now we can apply the IVT to see that $\tan$ is surjective onto $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $f:\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \tan(x)$.

**Proof of Surjectivity**

Suppose $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. We have to prove that $\exists \beta \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$  for which $f(\beta) = \alpha$.

We will use the Intermediate Value Theorem to prove that.

**Intermediate Value Theorem**

Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, and assume that $s$ lies between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. Then $\exists$ at least one $c \in [a, b]$ such that $f(c) = s$.

I omit the proof of the fact that $f:\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \tan(x)$ is continuous.

Let $-\infty < \alpha < \infty$, where $\infty = \lim_{x \to {\frac{\pi}{2}}^-} f(x)$ and, $-\infty = \lim_{x \to {-\frac{\pi}{2}}^+} f(x)$. Note that $\lim_{x \to {\pm \frac{\pi}{2}}} f(x)$ do not exists.

Then by the Intermediate Value Theorem, $\exists$ at least one $\beta \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ such that $f(\beta) = \alpha$.

It follows that $f$ is surjective.

This answer is inspired by the comments above.

Comment: (-1): I think this answer is labouring the point that a continuous and unbounded function is surjective and misses important details like proving that $\tan x$ is actually continuous and unbounded.